# Removing style after release is too late

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

When I activate the draggable I make the boxes a little bigger using padding with `animate`. Because animate causes a delay I can't remove all styling because of this delay.

```
$("#categories li").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-droppable-active').animate({
            padding: '10px'
        }, 300)
    },
    deactivate: function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

I think .ui-droppable-active fires again after the animation is done which causes the `deactivate` to fail. So if I release at 600ms with 5 li's it doesn't work for the last 3.

With 5 li's if I hold it for 1500ms it does work on all of them.

Comment: Have you tried with `stop`? something like `$(this).stop().removeAttr("style");`

Comment: Yes I did and that doesn't work either. There is another event being fired after the end of the animation.

Comment: My bad. After removing the animation from the `start` in the draggable and only having it in the `activate` of the droppable your solution worked. The `stop` of the draggable is more effective than the `deactivate` of the droppable.